# Let $K$ be an associative unital $F-algebra$. Is $(P(K), •)$ a $GF(2)-algebra$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $F$ be a field and let $K$ be an associative unital $F-algebra$. If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $K$, we let $A • B$ be the set of all elements of $K$ of the form $a • b$, with $a ∈ A$ and $b ∈ B$ (in particular, $∅ • B = A • ∅ = ∅$). We know that the set $V$ of all subsets of $K$ is a vector space over $GF(2)$ with $A+B=A\cup B\setminus A\cap B, 0A=∅,1A=A$. Is $V$ a $GF(2)-algebra$?

I think this is false, but I can think of a contradiction.

This is an exercise from the book: The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Should Know by Golan.

Comment: Are you sure there is no condition missing and you stated the problem correctly? What if $K=F$ for example?

Comment: yes, the problem is exactly like is statement by golan's book, so maybe is a typo

Comment: It would be quite strange. What if $v=1_K$? This can never be true.

Comment: Yes I thought that so, well then I will change the question to a problem were I need such a vector space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption is not true.

Let $A=\{0,1\}$ then $K=\mathscr{P}(A)$ is an associate and commutative unital $GF(2)-algebra$ with respect to the operation $∩$.

Now $V=\mathscr{P}(K)$ is again a vector space over $GF(2)$ and $\{∅\},\{\{1\}\},\{\{2\}\}\in V$, but $\{∅\}∙(\{\{1\}\}+\{\{2\}\})=\{∅\}∙\{\{1\},\{2\}\}=\{∅,∅\}=\{∅\}$ while $\{∅\}∙\{\{1\}\}+\{∅\}∙\{\{2\}\}=\{∅\}+\{∅\}=∅$ so ${∅}∙({{1}}+{{2}})\neq{∅}∙{{1}}+{∅}∙{{2}}

Therefore $(V,∙)$ is not a $GF(2)-algebra$.